# Checking multiple conditions and creating a new column according the check result in R

Tags: r, multiple-conditions

I would like to check TRUE,FALSE,TRUE and other seven combinations in my data frame which have 87027 rows and three columns.I want to write results for each row like that;

```
TRUE TRUE TRUE -> abc
TRUE TRUE FALSE-> ab
TRUE FALSE TRUE->ac
FALSE TRUE TRUE->bc
```

and others ...

Here is a simplified sample dataframe:

```
 A      B      C
TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
FALSE FALSE  FALSE
TRUE  FALSE  TRUE
FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

for this purpose I have written a for loop

```
for (i in 1:87027) {
    if (data$A[i]=="TRUE" & data$B[i]=="TRUE" ) {
        if (data$C[i]=="TRUE") {
            data$new[i]="abc"
        }
    }
    if (data$A[i]=="TRUE" & data$B[i]=="TRUE" ) {
        if (data$C[i]=="FALSE") {
            data$new[i]="ab"
        }
    }
    if (data$A[i]=="TRUE" & data$B[i]=="FALSE" ) {
        if (data$C[i]=="TRUE") {
            data$new[i]="ac"
        }
    }
    if (data$A[i]=="TRUE" & data$B[i]=="FALSE" ) {
        if (data$C[i]=="FALSE") {
            data$new[i]="a"
        }
    }
    if (data$A[i]=="FALSE" & data$B[i]=="FALSE" ) {
        if (data$C[i]=="FALSE") {
            data$new[i]="Nothing"
        }
    }
    if (data$A[i]=="FALSE" & data$B[i]=="TRUE" ) {
        if (data$C[i]=="TRUE") {
            data$new[i]="bc"
        }
    }
    if (data$A[i]=="FALSE" & data$B[i]=="TRUE" ) {
        if (data$C[i]=="FALSE") {
            data$new[i]="b"
        }
    }
    if (data$A[i]=="FALSE" & data$B[i]=="FALSE" ) {
        if (data$C[i]=="TRUE") {
            data$new[i]="c"
        }
    }
}
```

running this code take a few minutes , I wonder how can I do this a sophisticated way

Comment: That code hurts my heart

Comment: thanks  Dason,  I tried to solve my problem an oldest way because I am a new user in  R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Make some sample data (you should do this next time...)
n <- 87027
col <- 3
mat <- matrix(sample(c(T,F), n*col, rep=T), n, col)

# Function that does the conversion you want
# It takes in x which is assumed to be a vector of three logical
# values
f <- function(x){
  if(all(!x)){
    return("Nothing")
  }
  out <- paste(letters[1:3][x], collapse = "")
  return(out)
}

# Use f on every row of mat
output <- apply(mat, 1, f)
```

which yields

```
> head(mat)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> head(output)
[1] "a"       "b"       "Nothing" "ac"      "b"       "a"
```

And took very little time to run.